# How to fix 'cannot load such file -- socket' error on gem install

Tags: ruby, rvm

I'm not able to do `gem install` of any gem. When I try I get following error message

```
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
    cannot load such file -- socket
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

I use MacOS and `rvm` for versioning. Also, of note is that reinstall of ruby with openssl didn't work (which is referred as a solution for this problem on some answers on the internet).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't install gems because "undefined method \`invoke\_with\_build\_args' for nil:NilClass"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23350388/cant-install-gems-because-undefined-method-invoke-with-build-args-for-nilni)

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

`1. gem install bundler
 2. bundle install`

Comment: As I said in description, I'm not able to do `gem install` of anything including bundler